# I am designing one widget where I am facing a pixel overflow issue for scrollable listview horizontally

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  class DisplayPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DisplayPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<DisplayPage> createState() => _DisplayPageState();
}

class _DisplayPageState extends State<DisplayPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size mdata = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: mdata.height * 0.05,
            width: mdata.width,
            child: const TopBar(),
          ),
          Container(
            height: mdata.height * 0.95,
            color: Colors.amber,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TopBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const TopBar({super.key});

  @override
  State<TopBar> createState() => _TopBarState();
}

class _TopBarState extends State<TopBar> {
  List<String> buttonList = [];
  int counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: [
            TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Search')),
            TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Compare')),
            TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Learn')),
            TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Operation')),
            Container(
              width: buttonList.length * 40.0,
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: buttonList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
                  width: 40,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text(buttonList[index]),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  buttonList.add("B ${counter++}");
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Button Add'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Setting')),
            TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Hybrid')),
            TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Social')),
            TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Contact')),
            TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('About')),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I need my inner row items to scroll towards the right side when buttonList items are filled without pixel overflow issue. On click of Button Add I am adding an items in button List. But after some limit because of screen window size it gives pixel overflow issue. how to resolve this Pixel overflow issue? Any suggestions for this issue.

Comment: try wrapping the children (listview and row) inside Expanded widget each

Comment: @Picasso_20  Kindly, press the green tick as well, which is on the left side of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your ListView and Row with `Expanded` Widget like this :

```
class _TopBarState extends State<TopBar> {
  List<String> buttonList = [];
  int counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: [
              TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Search')),
              TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Compare')),
              TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Learn')),
              TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Operation')),
              Container(
                width: buttonList.length * 40.0,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: buttonList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
                    width: 40,
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text(buttonList[index]),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    buttonList.add("B ${counter++}");
                  });
                },
                child: const Text('Button Add'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Setting')),
              TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Hybrid')),
              TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Social')),
              TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Contact')),
              TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('About')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Row provides infinite width and horizontal listView also trying to take infinite width. You can wrap the ListView with Expanded widget.

```dart
class _TopBarState extends State<TopBar> {
  List<String> buttonList = [];
  int counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            // shrinkWrap: true,
            children: [
```